# Why my reputation doesn't change, even if I get votes and more than 24 hours have passed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Hi,
On July 24th I answered a question in stackoverflow, and it got 18 votes, mostly in the two days after.

On July 30th, I wrote another nice question and it got 12 votes, as you can see from my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95048/dalloliogm).

So, why do I only have 230 total reputation points*? I don't care too much about that, but I tought this may be an error of the website.

The only 'weird' thing I have done recently is that I have deleted an answer of mine, because it was not related to the question.
I am looking for that post but I can't find it now... maybe the question has been deleted, it was about how to delete the 4000th line of a file under Windows.

*now I have 330, because I got a bonus when I have registered here and associated the accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your 12 vote answer is a "community wiki" = no reputation

More info: [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-posts-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: ah!! ok sorry, I have missed it.

I didn't understand that when a question is converted to a community wiki, all the answers are also converted to that.

Answer (score 1):

I see you got the 180 points for the one answer. The other questions looks more like a "wiki" question and in that case points aren't given for those since those are usually not directly programming related.